# How to display most common words from a file of text, with equally common words displayed alphabetically

Tags: bash, sort

I am quite close so far, the script will sort the words and display most common to least common however when the words are equally common they need to be sorted.

```
cat > file.txt
tr -c '[:alpha:]' '[\n*]' < file.txt |
  sed -r '/^.{,5}$/d' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -20 | cut -c 9-
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check `man sort` carefully. You can supply multiple keys for a sort, and have the -r apply to the first key fields but not the second. Alternatively, you could invert the frequency arithmetically using `999999 - freq` in awk, and sort everything ascending (i.e. freq 30 sorts before 25 because 999969 < 999974).

Comment: The problem is i need the counter column to stick with its corresponding word, if i reversed the numbers and not the words it wouldn't help. Do you know how I can sort by the first key field then the second key field in the case of a tie? Possibly using -k?

Comment: Adding this line: sort -nk1r,1  -k2,2 makes it correctly fix the ordering issue however creates a new issue where it displays the highest 2 digit numbers before the highest 3 digit number (in terms of counters) which is a weird order.

Comment: @Trevor In `-nk1r,1 -k2,2`, `-n` is interpreted as global, i.e. it affects both `-k1r,1` and `-k2,2`. Compare it with `sort -b -k 1,1nr -k 2,2` (if your `sort` implementation supports it, you may also use the `--debug` option to see what is happening under the hood).

Comment: @Trevor  My bad: it would need to reverse the arithmetic afterwards. There is a whole sort method called DSU (decorate sort undecorate) originally in Python, where you put arbitrary key text on the front of each record, do a plain sort, and then clip off the key-text. For big files this can be faster than multiple keys specs, because complex keys are re-extracted O(n log n) times but decoration happens only O(n) times. DSU can also do things that key-specs can't do, like keep headers and footers in place.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant DSU predates Python, I believe.  It was a common pattern in Lisp, and became known as a "Schwartzian Transform" in the Perl community.  I found this to be an interesting read: https://www.perl.com/article/the-history-of-the-schwartzian-transform/

Answer (score 2):

`sort -nr` sorts lines in reverse numerical order. Since no key is specified, this only works on lines that start with a number, optionally preceded by one or more blank characters. After sorting by that initial number, some `sort` implementations (as [the standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/sort.html) encourages to) would perform a final, byte-by-byte sorting step on the lines that still collate equally.
At least with `sort` from GNU coreutils, the `-r` option is also applied to this last resort comparison, leading to:

```
$ printf '%s\n' '2 foo' '1 baz' '1 bar' '2 quux' | sort --debug -nr
sort: text ordering performed using ‘en_US.UTF-8’ sorting rules
2 quux
_
______
2 foo
_
_____
1 baz
_
_____
1 bar
_
_____
```

The sorting command you are looking for is likely:

```bsh
sort -b -k 1,1nr -k 2,2
```

Two `k`eys are specified: the first starts and ends at field 1 and has the `n`numeric and `r`everse modifiers applied; the second starts and ends at field 2 and, with no modifier applied, implies sorting by the rules of the current locale. The `-b` option makes `sort` ignore blank characters at the beginning of each sort key (not actually needed in your case, where the separator between the first and the second field is fixed).

What it does:

```
$ printf '%s\n' '2 foo' '1 baz' '1 bar' '2 quux' | sort --debug -b -k 1,1nr -k 2,2
sort: text ordering performed using ‘en_US.UTF-8’ sorting rules
2 foo
_
  ___
_____
2 quux
_
  ____
______
1 bar
_
  ___
_____
1 baz
_
  ___
_____
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `sort` or compatible, you can use the `-s` option for the second sort to avoid reordering the lines that have the same numeric value:

```
... | sort | uniq -c | sort -rns
```

(note that the NetBSD implementation of `sort` does that by default).